# EnableRetryOnFailure() and CommandTimeout() together

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to know if this syntax is correct.

```
sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure().CommandTimeout(60)
```

I would like connections to resume automatically but with a time out of 60s.

Regards